# Laravel 4: fetching only models that have related models

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

I want to only retrieve a model(s) when they have a specific related model present e.g.

```
$posts = Post::has('comment')->get();
```

that works fine although the opposite does not:

```
$comments = Comment::has('post')->get();
```

I get the following error:

```
Has method invalid on "belongsTo" relations.
```

Basically the reason i want to do this is that in exceptional circumstances there are cases that when i call a related model in a view, that model may not have a related model present (even when it should) sometimes due to bad data in the database etc....

```
{{ $jobApplication->job->title }}
```

obviously  gets the following error when that jobApplication has no job:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens cause, when you have a `1->n` relation on your database, the `n` part may **has** more than one register related to it. But, ain't the same the other way around. A `post` may have `n` comments, but a comment `belongs to` only one post. So, the method `has('model')` doesn't apply to this cases.

The solution for you problem, though, would be veirify if the variable is set. Try to do this on the controller.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks that did clear it up. Although wrapping things in if statements when accessing deeply nested models is cumbersome at best. E.g.`$person->address->street->name` (bad example but u get it)

Comment: ... sadly, you can't avoid it! All you can do is `@if(isset($the->whole->statemente->here))`. That would prevent from either need to check in every level first and from just throw a error screen in your face! :D