# How to get rid of "Trying to get property of non-object" errors for good?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-4, runtime-error

In various parts of my code I am trying to echo or otherwise use data from related models, such as

```
{{ $jobApplication->job->title }}
```

So far I am always using blade conditions to echo data only if it exists:

```
@if (! empty ($jobApplication->job))
{{ $jobApplication->job->title }}
@endif
```

...which is painful.

In a related question  ([Laravel 4: fetching only models that have related models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281465/laravel-4-fetching-only-models-that-have-related-models)) it is said that there is no workaround for this.

It seems I am not the only one wondering ([PHP - How to catch a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714591/php-how-to-catch-a-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error)) if this exception could be caught. However as the accepted answer points out, this "Trying to get propert of non-object" is not an exception, but rather is an error.

Is it really the only solution to add an almost endless amount of **if** clauses to check if the related model exists?

I mean, what would it take to make Laravel return "null" instead, when normally this error would be returned? Woudl it be a very stupid thing to do?

Comment: There are other solutions, I even lined it out with code earlier. But IIRC that would only work if blade is actually putting the variable expressions into string context which I don't know as I don't use Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
{{ isset($jobApplication->job) ? $jobApplication->job->title : ''  }}
```

Also you may fetching only models that have related models using something like this:

```
$jobApplication = JobApplication::has('job')->with('job')->get();
```

Now `$jobApplication` contains models with related `Job` model but only those `JobApplication` who has a related `Job` model with it.

Check [Querying Relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations).